# ExtJS 4 - Grid Column Editor Border Style when out of focus

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building an ExtJS4 web application and I have a grid where some of the columns have an editor in the form of text fields. However, the field is not visible until the user clicks on the grid cell.

Is there a way to place a border around the editor? So far I've tried editing the fieldStyle property of the textfield inside the column as such:

```
vertical-align: middle; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; border: 'black'
```

but that did not work.

```
{
      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
      renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
              return '<u>' + value + '</u>';
      },
      height: 30,
      maxHeight: 30,
      maxWidth: 100,
      minHeight: 30,
      minWidth: 100,
      width: 100,
      dataIndex: 'bank',
      text: 'BANK',
      editor: {
              xtype: 'textfield',
              height: '100%',
              width: '100%',
              fieldStyle: 'vertical-align: middle; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: \'Times New Roman\'; border: \'black\'',
      emptyText: 'Bank'
    }
 },
```

However, the renderer only returns 1 modification and I'm not sure how I can make it return 2 modifications (1 for the value and 1 for the borders).

### Update

The solution below works:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

However, I want a border around the field even if the field is out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off the syntax for border is not correct. Try "border: 1px solid black;"

secondly, if that doesn't work, assign a cls for this and do it through that class.

Comment: It woks when the field is on focus, is it possible to have a border even if the field is out of focus?

Comment: Yes. So pretty much you have to add a class using either "cls" or "bodyCls" or sometimes its called "bodyCssClass"... you have to look at the api for the specific object you are using. Place a class name on it, then in your CSS add that class and place the border there. If for some reason you need to tweak it, you will have to look into the dom using something like chrome web dev tools and find the specific element that you need to style.  
http://jsfiddle.net/carinlynchin/cb2Lahbp/    .....  you can look at this to get an idea of how to override ext's classes (that framework is a pain ...)